# Processing Algorithm output error when writing to MapInfo .tab

Tags: pyqgis

When I try to save algorithm output to MapInfo's .tab file format, I get a feature write error for every feature in the output.  This does not happen for .shp output. The error is:

> Feature could not be written to C:\Users\nganj\Desktop\TEST/EN/MapInfo/Eligible_Transport_Communities.tab: Feature creation error (OGR error: Failed writing attributes for feature id 1 in C:\Users\nganj\Desktop\TEST/EN/MapInfo/Eligible_Transport_Communities.tab)

```
outfile = parameters['DESTINATIONFOLDER'] + "/EN/MapInfo/Eligible_Transport_Communities.tab" 
    alg_params = {
        'FIELDS_MAPPING': [{'expression': parameters['ETCCOMMID'],'length': 0,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Number','precision': 0,'type': 2},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCNAMEEN'],'length': 150,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_en','precision': 0,'type': 10},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCNAMEFR'],'length': 150,'name': 'Eligible_Community_Name_fr','precision': 0,'type': 10},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCPROVINCE'],'length': 2,'name': 'Province_Territory','precision': 0,'type': 10},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCLATITUDE'],'length': 0,'name': 'Latitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCLONGITUDE'],'length': 0,'name': 'Longitude','precision': 6,'type': 6},
        {'expression': parameters['ETCSATDEP'], 'length': 15, 'name': 'Satellite_Dependent', 'precision': 0, 'type': 10}],
        'INPUT': parameters['EligibleTransportCommunities'],
        'OUTPUT': outfile
    }outputs['RefactorETCToEnglishLong'] = processing.run('native:refactorfields', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  The field length for the double types need to be >0